# How to get rid of "dev" postfix in version number when packaging a python module with devpi

Tags: python, setuptools, devpi

I use [devpi](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/) to deploy python modules. When I upload packages via `devpi upload` the generated module name always contains the 'dev' postfix after the version number. When I try to install those packages using `pip install ...` I have to specify the `--pre` flag. How do I get rid of this 'pre' postfix? I assume that I somehow have to mark the module as release version, but I have no clue how.

Comment: Not able to reproduce; what exactly have you run (exact command line of `devpi upload`, `pip install`).

Comment: Could you please share your setup.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect it is due to the fact that you have `tag_build = dev` somewhere. The most likely place for this is in a `setup.cfg` file if you have one although I think it could also be in your `setup.py` file. (Both of these files would live in the top level directory of your package code)

This is what my `setup.cfg` looks like:

```
[egg_info]
tag_build = dev
```

When I want to do a final release I remove the dev tag and leave it like this:

```
[egg_info]
tag_build =
```

The release then won't have the dev prefix any longer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be your version number in your setup.py (please do include specifics such as relevant files when posting).

`pip` determines what a pre-release version is as specified by [PEP 426](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/) (e.g. >=0.0.dev0) and so your version may be defined as a pre-release version. See [here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/logic.html#pre-release-versions).